# C-style pointers in Objective C collections

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers, nsarray

I need to change the value of an item I've put into an `NSMutableArray`, without actually knowing what variable it is.  Is that possible?  In C, I believe this could be done using a pointer

```
int i = 0;
int *j = &i;
*j = 5;
NSLog (@"'%d'",i); // Prints '5'
```

How do I translate this to Objective C?  So if I have 2 NSStrings that I put into an NSMutableArray:

```
NSString *text1 = @"Hello";
NSMutableString *text2 = @"World";
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:text1,text2,nil];
```

Then sometime later

```
[arr objectAtIndex:1] = @"Everyone";
NSLog (@"'%@'",text2); // I want this to print 'Everyone'
```

How would I do this?  This syntax gives an error `Expression is not assignable` on the first line of the last code block.

If I change this up a little to look more like the C code in the first code block:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:&text1,&text2,nil];
```

and

```
*[arr objectAtIndex:1] = @"Everyone"
```

I get an ARC error `Implicit conversion of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'id' is disallowed with ARC` on the first line and `Assigning to 'id' from incompatible type 'NSString *'` on the second line.  I've tried a few other slight adjustments to this, but all of them throw some error.

Clearly I'm not doing this right, but I have run out of ideas.

EDIT: It thinks I'm trying to create a new string and replace the string that I had at index 1 before.  That's not what I'm trying to do.  I'm basically trying to use an array to change the value of a variable without having to use the name of the variable (in my actual project, I won't know what it's name is when I need to change it).

Comment: Um, how is this not a question about programming?

Comment: "Minimal understanding".  Absent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing the different text is because objective C string are immutable, and you've actually inserted a new object into the array with this:
[arr objectAtIndex:1] = @"Everyone";

In your example, you can achieve what you're looking for by using NSMutableString instead, retrieving it from the array, and calling setString on it.

in the general case, if you are inserting an object into NSArray, and you're modifying the object, it WILL be reflected across all other references to it.

Comment: omg, so much derp.  I actually did declare my `text2` as `NSMutableString` for exactly the reason you mentioned, but then I forgot that I need to call `setString` to change it's value (instead of just `= @"Everyone"`).  I thought I had seen what you have in your last sentence somewhere, but when this didn't work, I assumed it wasn't the case and started looking all over for another way to do it, when I had the right idea all along, and was just using the wrong syntax to assign a new value.  I can't believe I missed that, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In all object oriented programming langauges like Objective-C we use objects for exactly that purpose.

So you are on the right track. NSArray or NSMutableArray respectively allows you to collect objects of any type and acces them with an index.

Your

```
[arr objectAtIndex:1] = @"Everyone";
```

really looks like

```
[arr addObject:@"Everyone"]; // That would add it to the end or

[arr insertObject:@"Everyone" atIndex:1]; // that would insert it at index 1.
```

Bare in mind that arrays start at index 0. 
And `arr` must be of type `NSMutabelArray` for this.

Modern Ojective-C compilers provide shortcuts such as

```
NSLog (@"index %d of the array: %@", 1, arr[1]);
```

Re your second question:

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"me", @"everybody else", nil]; //now goes as
NSArray *arr = @[@"me", @"everybody else"];
```

Comment: Good catch on the `NSMutableArray` part, but I think I didn't explain what I'm trying to do very well.  I don't want to replace what object I'm referring to in my array, I want to refer to the same object, but change it's value to something different.  Does that make sense?  I've edited my OP to try to explain my goal better.

Comment: @GeneralMike Sounds like you are looking for either `exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObject:` or a custom `CFArray` which you can add raw pointers to and then you can do `*CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(arr, idx) = foo`.